# How to allow all character types into an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im attempting to limit what the user can enter in each input... Everything is working as planned except the nothing() function:

I want this function to allow **ALL characters** to be entered into the inputs where onKeyDown="nothing();". For some reason the ones within the nothing() function follow the same layout as username (which is text and numbers only).

please help it will be much appreciated. Thanks for your time..

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="registration.php" method="post" name = "register" >
  <div style="width:50%; margin:auto;">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>
    <label for="username"><b>Username:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" pattern="[^-,]+" onKeyDown="ValidateName();" >

    <label style="width:50%" for="fname"><b>First Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name"  pattern="[^-,]+" name="fname" onKeyDown="ValidateFname();">

    <label for="lname"><b>Last Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ender Last Name" pattern="[^-,]+" name="lname" onKeyDown="ValidateLname();"><br><br>

    <label for="dob"><b>Date of Birth</b></label>
    <input type="date" placeholder="" name="dob"> <br><br>

    <label for="ingame"><b>In Game Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter In Game Name" name="ingame" onKeyDown="ValidateIGN();">

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" pattern="[^-,]+" onKeyDown="nothing()">

    <label for="pw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pw" pattern="[^-,]+" onKeyDown="nothing()">

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="confpw" pattern="[^-,]+" onKeyDown="nothing()">
    <button onclick="" name="register" type="submit" class="register">Register</button>
  </div>

  <div <div style="width:50%; margin;auto;">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in (unfinished)</a>.</p>
</form>
</body>
<footer>
<script>
function ValidateName() {

$("input").on("input", function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9|A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
})      //IE

}
</script>
<script>
function ValidateFname() {

$("input").on("input", function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
})      //IE

}
</script>
<script>
function ValidateLname() {

$("input").on("input", function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
})      //IE

}
</script>
<script>

function ValidateIGN() {

$("input").on("input", function(){
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
})      //IE

}
</script>
<script>

function nothing() {

$("input").on("input", function(){
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z|a-z|^-,]/g, ''));
})      //IE

}
</script>


</footer>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove all `onKeyDown="functionNameXXX();"` from input tag.

The problem is you are registering event every time when input value changes.

I just modified your code and it worked well.

**JS Code** remove all html inline method and add two handlers one for username and second for other names nothing to do with password and email if you are not willing to validate them.

```
//for validating username 
$('input[name="username"]').keyup( function (e,i) {
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9|A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
}) ;


//for validating fname, lname and IGN
$('.name').keyup(function (){
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
});
```

**HTML** remove `onkeydown` from all input and added class in fname, lname and IGN fields

```
 <form action="registration.php" method="post" name = "register" >
  <div style="width:50%; margin:auto;">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>


    <label for="username"><b>Username:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" pattern="[^-,]+"   >

    <label style="width:50%" for="fname"><b>First Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name"   pattern="[^-,]+" name="fname"  class="name" >

    <label for="lname"><b>Last Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ender Last Name" pattern="[^-,]+" name="lname"  class="name"><br><br>

    <label for="dob"><b>Date of Birth</b></label>
    <input type="date" placeholder="" name="dob"> <br><br>

    <label for="ingame"><b>In Game Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter In Game Name" name="ingame" class="name">

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" pattern="[^-,]+"  >

    <label for="pw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pw" pattern="[^-,]+" >

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="confpw" pattern="[^-,]+"  >
    <button onclick="" name="register" type="submit" class="register">Register</button>
  </div>

  <div <div style="width:50%; margin;auto;">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in (unfinished)</a>.</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your pattern for nothing is wrong (will throw error) ,

you said it will accept all charcter , so just remove the keyDown event no need for the nothing function ...

```js
function ValidateName() {

  $("input").on("input", function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9|A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
  }) //IE

}

function ValidateFname() {

  $("input").on("input", function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
  }) //IE

}

function ValidateLname() {

  $("input").on("input", function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
  }) //IE

}

function ValidateIGN() {

  $("input").on("input", function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z|a-z]/g, ''));
  }) //IE

}
/*
function nothing() {

  $("input").on("input", function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z|a-z][^-,]/g, ''));
  }) //IE

}
*/
```

```css
input {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:50%; margin:auto;">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>
    <label for="username"><b>Username:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" pattern="[^-,]+" onKeyDown="ValidateName();">

    <label style="width:50%" for="fname"><b>First Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" pattern="[^-,]+" name="fname" onKeyDown="ValidateFname();">

    <label for="lname"><b>Last Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ender Last Name" pattern="[^-,]+" name="lname" onKeyDown="ValidateLname();"><br><br>

    <label for="dob"><b>Date of Birth</b></label>
    <input type="date" placeholder="" name="dob"> <br><br>

    <label for="ingame"><b>In Game Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter In Game Name" name="ingame" onKeyDown="ValidateIGN();">

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" pattern="[^-,]+" onKeyDown="nothing()">

    <label for="pw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pw" pattern="[^-,]+">

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="confpw" pattern="[^-,]+">
    <button onclick="" name="register" type="submit" class="register">Register</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: the reason i added it was because it isnt worrking. ive tried alot of different things but they keep acting like the ValidateName function

Comment: There is something , wrong in your code , without onkeypressed should work correctly !!!

Answer (score 0):

### Wrong parts:

- You can't use `this` when you are using html inline event listeners.
- $('input') means every input, which will bind same events to every input, causing duplication every times when you input text.

### What should you do:

1. Try not to use inline event listeners.
   This is more like an advice, but it makes your code harder to read and harder to manage. Try to bind events from JS.
2. Again, $('input') means literally every input in document, which will prevent you from making separate filters. You should select elements with more specific selectors, such as $("input[name='username']"). You can see various selectors from here : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

This will be your code :

```js
$("input[name='username']").on('input', function(){
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/g, ''));
})
$("input[name='fname']").on('input', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''));
})
$("input[name='lname']").on('input', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''));
})
$("input[name='ingame']").on('input', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''));
})
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form action="registration.php" method="post" name = "register" >
          <div style="width:50%; margin:auto;">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
            <hr>
            <label for="username"><b>Username:</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">

            <label style="width:50%" for="fname"><b>First Name:</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="fname">

            <label for="lname"><b>Last Name:</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ender Last Name" name="lname"><br><br>

            <label for="dob"><b>Date of Birth</b></label>
            <input type="date" placeholder="" name="dob"> <br><br>

            <label for="ingame"><b>In Game Name:</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter In Game Name" name="ingame">

            <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">

            <label for="pw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pw">

            <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="confpw">
            <button onclick="" name="register" type="submit" class="register">Register</button>
          </div>

          <div style="width:50%; margin;auto;">
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in (unfinished)</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```